# Ecto belongs_to changeset insert inserts in both relations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, changeset

### Introduction

I have a problem with relations in Ecto. I have two schemas *User* and *Role*, and I want to be able to insert a new *User* with a foreign key in DB to *Role* table.

The problem is every time I try to insert a new user, it doesn't have a relation to the *Role* table (*role_id* column is null in *User* table). I tried to build an assoc in order to create the relation but it doesn't work.

---

### Current code

My *User* schema is:

```
  schema "user" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :encrypted_password, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true

    belongs_to :role, TestApp.Role

    timestamps()
  end
```

*Role* schema:

```
  schema "role" do
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()

    has_many :users, TestApp.User
  end
```

I defined the *User* changeset as the following:

```
  @required_fields ~w(first_name last_name email password)
  @optional_fields ~w(encrypted_password)

  @required_update_fields ~w()
  @optional_update_fields ~w(first_name last_name email password encrypted_password role)


  def create_changeset(struct, params \\ :empty) do
    changeset(struct, params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end

  def update_changeset(struct, params \\ :empty) do
    changeset(struct, params, @required_update_fields, @optional_update_fields)
  end

  defp changeset(struct, params \\ :empty, required_field, optional_fiels) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, required_field, optional_fiels)
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/, message: "invalid format")
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 5)
    |> validate_confirmation(:password, message: "password does not match")
    |> unique_constraint(:email, message: "email already taken")
    |> generate_encrypted_password
  end
```

And *Role* changeset:

```
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
    |> unique_constraint(:name)
  end
```

In my *UserController*, I have a *create method*:

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.create_changeset(%User{}, user_params)

    case User.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:ok)
        |> render(TestApp.UserRender, "show.json", user: user)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        handle_user_creation_validation_error(conn, changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

### Tested solutions (without success)

I tested several options, the following list it's just an example of what I tried so far (too many tries). It doesn't have to compile at all, i'll just post it as information.

I tried to create a *insert* method inside *User* to build an assoc and save the changeset.

```
  def insert(changeset) do
    if changeset.valid? do
      IEx.pry
      TestApp.Role.find_by_name("user")
      |> Ecto.build_assoc(:users)
      |> Ecto.change(changeset.params)
      |> Repo.insert
    else
      {:error, changeset}
    end
  end
```

I tried also get the role and build an assoc

```
TestApp.Role.find_by_name("user")
|> TestApp.Repo.preload(:users)
|> Ecto.build_assoc(:users)
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:users, user)
|> Repo.insert!
```

I saw this example in the Ecto documentation

```
  def insert(changeset) do
    Repo.transaction fn ->
      TestApp.Role.find_by_name("user")
      |> TestApp.Repo.preload(:users)
      |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:users, [changeset])
      |> Repo.insert
  end
```

### Current status

I was able to create relations between *users* and *roles*, but every time I inserted a new *user* a new *role* role was inserted also (I was shocked, it just create a one_to_one relation every time!).

I know there is a right way to this, but I wonder if it will imply a preload of `:users` from a *role* first. I don't think that it's an acceptable solution, hope someone could explain all this about relations, preloads and saving the changesets.

### Solution

Well, seems that it's necessary send the FK as a param in the *User* changeset, so I had to change the param field `role` with `role_id`.

A param body request example might be:

```
{
    "user" : {
        "first_name": "first name",
        "last_name": "last name",
        "email": "test@email",
        "password": "longtestpassword",
        "password_confirmation": "longtestpassword",
        "role_id": 1
    }
}
```

I added also a `cast_assoc` to the changeset validation pipeline:

```
|> cast_assoc(:role)
```

The `User.insert/1` implementation was removed and the controller calls `Repo.insert/1` instead.

---

**Thank you for your help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@optional_update_fields ~w(... role)
```

to:

```
@optional_update_fields ~w(... role_id)
```

and then send just role_id in your params instead of map of role fields

Comment: btw i think you should move first_name, last_name and email to required fields, because you probably don't want to clear them and remove encrypted_password from update fields entirely, because it's something that you want to generate in background

Comment: That worked fine. Thank you! I added also a `|> cast_assoc(:role)` in the user changeset to validate the relation first. I wonder why building and assoc doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use these way to deal this situation:

From `user` side:

1. directly put the `role_id`(which is certain `Role.id`) in `User changese attrs`, so after Repo.insert(user), this new user will have `ForeignKey` of `Role`, like this:

> ```
> def changeset(%User{}=user, %{.., role_id: certain_role_id}=attrs) do
>   user 
>   |> cast(attrs, [...,:role_id]
>   |> validate_require([:role_id, ...])
> ```

2. [build_assoc](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#build_assoc/3), in fact works like last one, just push "role_id" 
   into `user`, but more beautiful..

From `role` side:

1. [put_assoc](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4), used in the `Role changeset`, it will manager all `users` associated with current `role` by `put_assoc(:users, [user_changeset_lists])`.Due to the `put_assoc` do not check the data, so better to do `changeset` manual;,like this:

> ```
> def changeset(%Role{}=role, new_user) do
>   users = Repo.preload(role, :users)
>   users = user ++ User.changeset(new_user)
>   role
>   |> cast(..)
>   |> validate_required(..)
>   |> put_assoc(:users, users)
> end
> ```

2. [cast_assoc](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3) like add `user` for `role` without affectting alreasy related `user`, and `cast_assoc` will auto invoke `User.changeset`, like this:

> ```
> def changeset(%Role{}=role, %{users: [new_user1, new_user2]}) do
>   role
>   ...
>   |> cast_assoc(:users)
> end
> ```